# c++ structure alignment padding on 32 vs 64 bit

Tags: c++, struct, 32bit-64bit

Consider the following c++ structure declarations:

```cpp
struct SFoo
{
    int A = 200;
};

struct SBar
{
    SFoo Foo = SFoo();
    SBar* Bar = this;
};
```

- why is `offsetof(SBar, Bar) == 8` when compiled for 64 bit even tho `sizeof(SFoo) == 4` ?
- why is is it different for 32 bit (`offsetof(SBar, Bar) == 4` as I would expect it on 64 bit too) ?

Comment: Structure alignment padding bytes.

Comment: What are you really trying to do? What problem could `*(uintptr_t*)(((uintptr_t)pBaz) + sizeof(int) + sizeof(SFoo))` possibly solve?

Comment: Use [`offsetof`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/offsetof)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I'm injecting a DLL into a process in order to read memory of that process; so in my real code I don't have `pBaz` defined and rather need to read it by memory (I know the struct address + offset of the field). This was just an example to simplify the code. The actual code would look like `*(uintptr_t*)(0x12345 + 0x67)`.

Comment: @SolomonUcko I forgot to include that I don't have the structures `SBar`, `SFoo` and `SBaz` defined in my real code and thus can't use `offsetof`. I've added a note to the example code.

Comment: Do you know which compiler was used to build the program you're trying to "hack"? Do you know its exact alignment and padding rules? It could change not only between different compilers, but also between versions of a single compiler. And most importantly, are you really 100% sure about the order of the data you try to access? The provider of the program you try to hack might actually change the order between releases of its program, as a cheap way to foil attempts like this. Or they just added more fields to their structures?

Comment: @Eljay but why would the alignment padding of `SBaz` and `SBar` differ in this case and how do I fix that for 64 bit ?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Yes I know those and I actually know my addresses and offsets are correct (because I can read them properly by defining the struct for it) but it does not even matter for this question. The example code provided here still produces the behavior I'm talking about and I don't know why that is happening. Here's ogdb link: https://onlinegdb.com/fte2zzcDd.

Comment: The very first comment answered that question: Struct padding. You are meddling with the realm of "implementation defined behavior". There is no reason as far as the language is concerned. The compiler considered it best to do it this way given the parameters. There is nothing "wrong" here.

Comment: @DevSolar I didnt meant to say that is wrong behavior but it is very unexpected to me because in the (updated) example above `SFoo` would perfectly fit within 4 bytes but yet `SBar::Foo` is expanded to 8 bytes on 64 bit (msvc, gcc). That seems kinda strange to me and I wanted to know why that is happening.

Comment: The usual reason for padding bytes is because on many CPUs it is more efficient to access data that is at a word-aligned address.

Comment: `struct { char c; int x; }` isn't size 5 either...

Comment: Isn't `SBar` perfectly word-aligned here already because `SFoo` is 4 bytes ? I don't understand what the purpose of those extra 4 bytes would be in this case.

Comment: @DevSolar as far as I understand the padding (and this is probably what I didn't get correct) it would add 3 bytes for `c` because it wants all members to be aligned to multiples of 4. But in my example above `SFoo` *is* 4 bytes. Why would the compiler want to pad it to 8 in `SBar::Foo` ? It appears something is wrong with my understanding of the purpose of alignment padding or their details and I thought there is a definitive answer to this scenario.

Comment: The answer is just that x86 and x86_64 have different pointer sizes and thus pointer alignment requirements.  x86_64 pointers are 8 bytes and like being aligned on 8-byte boundaries, while x86 pointers are only 4 bytes and like being aligned on 4-byte boundries.

Comment: @MilesBudnek Ah okey, so `SBar::Foo` is aligned to 8 bytes because there is a pointer coming next to it. Thanks, I realy didn't understand that!

Comment: @SuperEwald - To be formal, the rule is "structs can have padding after each member". That is the whole rule, which leaves everything up to the compiler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bar is a 64bit pointer and thus needs to be aligned to an 8 byte address. It is implicitly padded. Additionally you can check alignment requirements using `alignof()`.